# Livewire 3 no despliega valor de variable recibida por parametro y mount()

Tags: livewire, laravel-9

Tengo un componente CausasComponent desde donde llamo al componente ManagerComponent. Ambos son de página completa. Le paso como parámetro un modelo Causa $causa. Lo recibo en managerComponent con mount() pero luego no puedo desplegarlo en la vista. No muestra nada.

La llamada:

```
<td class="td-actions text-right" style="width: 10%;">
    <a class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm d-inline" 
        href="{{ route('manager',  $causa) }}" 
        title="Gestionar causa">
        <i class="bi bi-gear"></i>
    </a>
</td>
```

la ruta:

```
Route::get('/manager/{causa}', ManagerComponent::class)->name('manager');
```

la rececpción en ManagerComponent

```
class ManagerComponent extends Component
{
    
    public $title = 'Causas';
    public Causa $causa;
    
    public function mount(Causa $causa)
    {
        $this->causa = $causa;
        
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.causas.manager-component')
            ->layout('livewire.causas.layouts.manager');
    }
}
```

El despliegue en la vista

```
<div>
    {{$title }}  {{ $causa->name }}  
</div>
```

Si pongo un dd($causa) en mount() puedo ver el valor de $causa que llegó efectivamente. Pero no lo despliega en la vista. NO arroja error. Solo no muestra nada.